# Defining spinner in xml with arrow

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a Spinner control in my android project.

Here is my xml markup for the spinner

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/skyblue"
    android:entries="@array/hour_arrays"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:prompt="@string/hour_select"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

This does not have any drop down arrow (which supposedly is there by default?) and as such to the untrained user it does not look like it can be clicked.

What am I missing?

Comment: You will have to create a custom spinner for this, a separate xml having the Arrow you want to be there, else you can take the spinner and a small ImageView in a RelativeLayout and stick them togather to make it look like spinner is having an Arrow

Comment: Just remove this line android:background="@color/skyblue" and refer the link http://stephenpengilley.blogspot.de/2013/01/android-custom-spinner-tutorial.html